# How to warn user of CAPS LOCK enabled in Flex/AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air

Similar to the XP login screen, in Flex 3, how can I display a warning to the user in a textbox that the CAPS LOCK key is enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flash.ui.Keyboard.capsLock is not bindable so that code won't really work.

I would invoke a function in the "keyDown" event for the TextInput and then check flash.ui.Keyboard.capsLock in that function.  You can then set visible/includeInLayout on that Text, pop up an Alert, etc...

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
private function addHandler():void{
        //Called from app's creation complete event.
        //Listener to handle any keyboard KEY_DOWN event:
        this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handleKeyDown);
    }


private function handleKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
     if (Keyboard.capsLock){
          lblCaps.visible =true;
     } else {
          lblCaps.visible =false;   
     }
}
```

call addHandler on creation complete

Answer (score 1):

In actionScript:

```
if(flash.ui.Keyboard.capsLock){
    // caps lock is on...
}
```

or MXML:

```
<mx:Box width="100%" id="capsbox"
    visible="{flash.ui.Keyboard.capsLock}" 
    includeInLayout="{capsbox.visible}">
        <mx:Text text="Caps Lock is on." color="red" />
</mx:Box>
```

Comment: I created a blank form and dropped it on the form. It doesn't work, even if CAPS LOCK is on when I start the app. Do I need a keyboard handler?